# How to access variable key and use it as a variable in another function?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm sorry about the title I'm not sure what is the name of the issue I'm trying to solve.

Assume I have the following class with a function

```
{
 printInfo(age){
 console.log(name)
 console.log(age)
 }
}
```

From another page I want to call the class like this:
`someClass.Mike.printInfo(21)`, and the function would print Mike and 21. Of course, the name `Mike` is variable so it can be anything.

Is there a way to accomplish that? Maybe something special in the constructor of the class? some JSON object keys manipulations?

Thank you.

Comment: Your question is very unclear; you don't "call" classes, for one, and all your JS is on every page in which you've included the script tags . Do you mean you want to access the class method `printInfo()` from some other context? And what you're asking w/r to the name is completely unclear. Do you mean you `someClass[var_containing_property_name].printInfo()`? Why wouldn't `printInfo()` just be a method of `someClass` so you can access it whenever you want, and provide the name along with the age as arguments, ie `someClass.printInfo(Mike, 21)`?

Comment: What you are asking for is impossible. At the time when you use the value of a variable or a property, you cannot know what the variable or a property name was. So if you call `myFunction()` or `myObject.myMethod()` you don't actually have those names available. At most you can have named functions, e.g., `function someFunction() {}` but if you then do `someNewName = someFunction` you are still unable to figure out if you've called `someFunction()` or `someNewName()` at execution time.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Yes I'm trying to do someClass[var_containing_property_name].printInfo() and use that var_containing_property_name inside the printInfo(). I was trying to see if there is a way to do that. I did not want to say it is impossible right away, I wanted to see if there is something I'm missing. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have stored the Names somewhere for example:

```
const names = ['Mike', 'Dave'];
```

you could access the function, if it is indeed stored in the regarding objects with dynamic properties like this:

```
names.forEach(name => {
   someClass[name].printInfo(21);
})
```

If that is not what you need you should try to write your question a little bit more detailed.

The statement from another page is also a little bit confusing, if the class is not defined on the page than you cannot access it.

Comment: Thank you, but that's not what I'm looking for. That is just an array and you are calling the method on the array items.

Comment: I am not calling the methods on the array items I am calling the methods on the objects someClass which are named as the array items

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to pass any variables being used. You can do so by separating them:

```
    printInfo(name, age)
```

To use it, you'd call the method like so:

```
    SomeClass.printInfo("Mike", 21);
```

Comment: Thank you. But I was trying to find a solution where name is not part of the variables that go inside that function, instead it is in someClass."variable".printInfo(age).

Answer (score 0):

Create an instance for each person and pass the name in the constructor then call `printInfo()` from an instance to get the name and age :

```js
class SomeClass {
 
   constructor(name, age) {
     this.name = name;
     this.age = age;
   }
 
   printInfo(age){
     console.log(this.name)
     console.log(age || this.age)
   }
}

const mike = new SomeClass('Mike');
mike.printInfo(21);

const jean = new SomeClass('Jean', 17);
jean.printInfo();
```

Or you can get your result using Objects:

```js
const Mike = {
  printInfo: (age) => { console.log('Mike'); console.log(age) }
};

const Jean = {
  printInfo: (age) => { console.log('Jean'); console.log(age) }
};

const someClass = {
 Mike,
 Jean
};

someClass.Mike.printInfo(21);
someClass.Jean.printInfo(17);

// Or:
// let name = 'Mike';
// someClass[name].printInfo(21);
// name = 'Jean';
// someClass[name].printInfo(17);
```

Or even better:

```js
const constructObject = (name) => ({
  printInfo: (age) => { console.log(name); console.log(age) }
});

const someClass = {
 Mike: constructObject('Mike'),
 Jean: constructObject('Jean')
};

someClass.Mike.printInfo(21);
someClass.Jean.printInfo(17);

// Or:
// let name = 'Mike';
// someClass[name].printInfo(21);
// name = 'Jean';
// someClass[name].printInfo(17);
```